# A trigonometric identity

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-series, mathematical-physics

If one sees the simplification done in equation $5.3$ (bottom of page 29) of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0310285v6.pdf) it seems that a trigonometric identity has been invoked of the kind,

$$\ln(2) + \sum _ {n=1} ^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n\theta)}{n} = - \ln \left\vert \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right\vert $$

Is the above true and if yes then can someone help me prove it?

Comment: Are you familiar with writing $\cos$ as a sum of complex exponentials? Are you familiar with the Taylor series expansion of $-\log(1-x)$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint 1:** Use that
$$
\log(1-z)=-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n}
$$

**Hint 2:** Set 
$$
z=r e^{i\theta}
$$

**Hint 3:** Take a real part

**Hint 4:** Take a limit $r\to 1-0$ and use [Abel's summation formula](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Abel_summation_method)

Comment: Just a small remark : in the second step, some work is required to justify convergence (one might use Abel's summation formula for example).

Comment: ...finally: $1-\cos\,\theta=2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}$

Comment: @Joel, yes, since $|\exp\,i\theta|=1$, which is exactly the boundary of the convergence region of the series being used...

Comment: MSE users are always on alert, thanks for your remarks!

Comment: For people not used to Norbert's notation in Hint 4: what he wrote is the same as $r\to1^{-}$ (that is, approach from the left).

Comment: @J.M. Is this notation is not common?

Comment: It's not as common as the one I was talking about, I've found, so I mentioned it for completeness.

Comment: @J.M.The same notation used in the reference I've posted in my answer

Comment: Thanks for the help! The identity is very curious to me inspite of having been doing advanced mathematics for years now. Is it part of some general thinking..which seems I have missed out on! @J.M I initially did try by writing as you suggest $sin (\frac{\theta}{2})$ in terms of $cos(\theta)$ and then taking the log of it but that doesn't seem to produce the answer..is there such a direct way to get there?

Comment: @6818, you still need to take the series route...